# Mysql Query SUM field string and group by

Tags: php, mysql

I have a talbe name is **laporan** ,
current query is

> "SELECT * FROM laporan"

and then if i print_r i get result data like this:

> ```
> [0] => Array
>     (
>         [tanggal_laporan] => 2012-11-04
>         [total_kas] => Rp 21.000,-
>     )
>
> [1] => Array
>     (
>         [tanggal_laporan] => 2012-11-04
>         [total_kas] => Rp 50.500,-
>     )
>
> [2] => Array
>     (
>         [tanggal_laporan] => 2012-11-04
>         [total_kas] => Rp 56.000,-
>     )
>
> [3] => Array
>     (
>         [tanggal_laporan] => 2012-11-05
>         [total_kas] => Rp 89.000,-
>     )
>
> [4] => Array
>     (
>         [tanggal_laporan] => 2012-11-05
>         [total_kas] => Rp 73.000,-
>     )
> ```

I want to SUM field **total_kas** which this field is varchar/string, my question is there a way/can to SUM a field varchar/string. and then this query group_by **tanggal_laporan**, So i want to get data as below:

> ```
> [0] => Array
>     (
>         [tanggal_laporan] => 2012-11-04
>         [total_kas] => 127500
>     )
>
> [1] => Array
>     (
>         [tanggal_laporan] => 2012-11-05
>         [total_kas] => 162000
>     )
> ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (assuming that `total_kas` always has the form 'Rp NUMBER,-'):

```
SELECT tanggal_laporan, SUM(CAST(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(total_kas, '.', ''), ' ', -1), ',', 1)
    AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)) AS num 
FROM laporan 
GROUP BY tanggal_laporan
```

I have done some changes to deal with integer numbers. Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d3d3/11) example.
Remove the `UNSIGNED` is it doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: I noticed now that your string is slightly more complex, give me a minute to fix it.

Comment: This is a message error. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '', `-1)`, `UNSIGNED` INTEGER)), `laporan`.* FROM (`laporan`) GROUP BY `tanggal_laporan' at line 1

Comment: Hi cyanical, I've decided that I did replace the time when insert data into mysql (POST to mysql), I do so that this query is not heavy if using with add function-function in mysql, and finally I just use the sum(total_kas) as total_sum, and the issue was over. thanks man.